# How to access the "Videos uploaded by" playlist in someone's channel?

Tags: youtube, youtube-playlist

I was searching for a video and I ended up following this URL: http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=UUmKurapML4BF9Bjtj4RbvXw which seems to be an automatically generated playlist out of all the videos from those (awesome) guys' channels. So I was trying to access the very same playlist from their YouTube channel, but I couldn't find the link.

What's the way to access such playlist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to the user's profile page on YouTube: `https://www.youtube.com/user/<username>/`
2. Hover over/tap on **Recent Videos** and a Play button should appear:

[image]

Comment: Brill! Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!